# @OneToOne java persist with @entity

Tags: java, hibernate, persist

I have a problem with persist a new account, when I am running my AccountIT test. The **error** I get is:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: no.phasfjo.dto.Customer

I figure it has to do something with the `@OnToOne` annotation, but I cannott figure out how to change it correctly?

http://pastebin.com/w4z8PArY

Comment: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: no.phasfjo.dto.Customer. at no.phasfjo.infrastructure.account.JpaAccountDao.persist(JpaAccountDao.java:26),

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had this error, when I called: `entityManager.persist(...);` on an object which already was saved (and thus it has an ID). To fix it, I sould not have called `entityManager.persist(...)`, but `entityManager.merge(...)`. Maybe this is the same problem as you have a.t.m.

(the pastebin doesn't really show what the real problem is, so I'm guessing... Am I right?)

Comment: Hii Jeroen, i am sorry i did not put in all the error messages. I will try to change it. But i get the same error: detached entity passed to persist: no.phasfjo.dto.Customer.

Comment: I checked your pastebin again... Still I haven't fount thé problem... But maybe.... your toString() has these two lines: `", customer=" + customer +` \n `", customer= '" + login +` -- should it not be login= ?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the fact that you may be misusing `@OneToOne` annotation. In JPA `@OneToOne` means that the primary key of `Customer` is the same as the Primary key of `Account` and again for `Login`. As they are one-to-one they cannot exist independently without each other and as soon as they do you start getting these errors.

You have two options,

- change your annotation to `@OneToMany` or
- do not persist `Customer` and `Login` in your test rather instantiate them and then instantiate `Account` with `Customer` and `Login` and finally call persist once only on `Account` and never on `Customer` or `Login`.

Comment: Thank you. I have a bit of a logical problem. Because this is a demo webshop project. I am trying to figure out the relationship between the entity. One account holds one customer, with one login service (username, password). Does that sounds correct?

Comment: Btw  - it worked with the instantiating , and then only persist the Account. Thank you, question solved =)

Comment: Basically I only use `@OneToOne` mappings when I believe a child object cannot exist without the parent object. Taking your example i would say `Login` should never exist without an `Account` or `Customer` so `@OneToOne` is correct you just have to remember to not save the child objects independently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so i am on the right track =)